# Euler 14. Answer doesn't match

Tags: java

```
public class problem14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int biggest = 0;
        int biggestNum =0;
        for(int i = 1; i<1000001;i++){
            if(Solve(i)>biggest){
                biggest = Solve(i);
                biggestNum = i;     
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Chain: " + biggest + "Number: " + biggestNum);  
    }

    public static boolean evenorodd(int num){
        //returns true if even, and returns false if odd
        int lastNum = num %  10;
        if(lastNum==0||lastNum==2||lastNum==4||lastNum==6||lastNum==8){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }   
    } 

    public static int Solve(int num){
        int count = 1;
        int end = 0;

        while(end!=1){
            if(evenorodd(num)){
                num = num/2;
                count+=1;
                if(num==1){
                    end=1;
                    return count;
                }
            }
            if(!evenorodd(num)){
                num = 3*num +1;
                count+=1;
                if(num==1){
                    end=1;
                    return count;
                }
            }   
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Sorry guys, I already look up those problem 14 solutions, and I still couldn't figure out why my code doesn't give me the right answer. Please help me, I have trying to figure out for almost a hour now. I just need to know why I am not getting the right answer, since I have been testing out a lot of numbers.

Comment: C'mon, what sort of sense of achievement will you get if we solve it for you? :-)

Comment: An hour is nothing! If you have no syntax problems then it boils down to logic. Work on it, it's more satisfying when you finally get to the answer yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that in your `Solve()` method,you are checking `if(evenorodd(num))` and `if(!evenorodd(num))` separately! Because of this even in case,if your num is even and is processed to yield true result but num becomes 1 at last,and hence it is also getting processed by `if(!evenorodd(num))` because it has turned 1 `// an odd number`.

**Second**,instead of directly returning `count` from if-else block,you should better use `break` statement for exiting the loop and finally returning count!

Try reducing it to `if(evenorodd(num)){...} else {...}`.

Workout for your `int Solve(num)` method to ease your effort :-

```
public static int Solve(int num){
    int count = 1;
    int end = 0;

    while(end!=1){
        if(evenorodd(num)){
            num = num/2;
            count+=1;
            if(num==1){
                end=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        else 
         {
            num = 3*num +1;
            count+=1;
            if(num==1){
                end=1;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    return count;
}
```

I hope it helps and you obtain the correct answer! BEST WISHES...

Answer (score -2):

Your algorithm is fine. You're blowing out on the range of an int.  Use longs instead.

[A Groovy solution for Project Euler 14](http://keyzero.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/project-euler-problem-14/)

I got the above down-voted, so here's some more detail.

Shekhar is right, you shouldn't be retesting the same condition, but it's actually non-material to your algorithm in this case. A cycle can only complete from the first condition, an even number, anyway. The blog post talks about this and other optimisations you can do to speed up the computation.

You need to make "num" a long, even with the revised non-repeated test algorithm or at various points in your cycle it will exceed the range of an int, and this'll then give you a wrong answer.

Also, you shouldn't call Solve() twice in the outer "i" loop either, store the result of the first call in a variable and just assign it if it's greater.

All that said, you don't need all that code. Less code means less stuff that can go wrong.  Here's a simple implementation of a Solve() function that does the job.

```
    public static int Solve(long num) {

    int count = 1;

    while (num > 1) {
        num = (num & 1) == 0 ? num / 2 : 3 * num + 1;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

(num & 1) masks off all the bits except the last, so it leaves 0 for an even number, and 1 for an odd number. It's just a shorthand way of doing your evenorodd() function.

The =?: syntax (if you've not seen it before - this is a ternery operator) does the test, then what to return if true, then what to return if false.  Again, just a shorthand for an if-then-else where you need to do a single value assignment.

Hope this helps.